# The function object has no attribute 'entry_set'

Tags: django

[image]

[image]

Something about Django 
Just as the photo show 
I don't know why there is has a AttributeError

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Topic
def topic(request, topic_id):
   topics = Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)
   entries = topic.entry_set.order_by('-date_added')
   context = {'topic': topic, 'entries': entries}
return render(request, 'learning_logs/topic.html', context)
```

Comment: Please provide sample code and error output directly here and without external image sources. Your question title is also not descriptive. It should tell something about the question.

Comment: I had add the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is probably in your topic function. You assign one topic to the `topics` variable and then try to get an entry_set off a variable called `topic` instead of `topics`. Since you're only getting one topic it would make more sense to change the `topics` variable to singular `topic`:

```
def topic(request, topic_id):
   topic = Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)
   entries = topic.entry_set.order_by('-date_added')
   context = {'topic': topic, 'entries': entries}
   return render(request, 'learning_logs/topic.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the models Topic and Entry, and Topic is related to Entry through a foreign key.

Then you can get entries using "`topic.entry_set.order_by('-date_added')`"

FYI: `entry_set is XXX_set.all() XXX` means Entry model.