# Python Crash Course, Chapter 18 - AttributeError: 'Pizza' object has no attribute 'entry_set'

Tags: python, django

I've just made it to the end of chapter 18 (Getting Started with Django) of Eric Matthas' [Python Crash Course](http://file.allitebooks.com/20160102/Python%20Crash%20Course.pdf). I have the below function, Pizza, in views.py which is raising the Attribute error noted below.

```
AttributeError: 'Pizza' object has no attribute 'entry_set'
```

This error occurs while I'm viewing my site and click the link for a specific pizza. Taking this action should open a new view (i.e. a page on the site) which displays the name of the pizza along with a list of toppings (i.e. it should execute the pizza function below).

```
def pizza(request,pizza_id):
    """Show the toppings for a pizza"""
    pizza = Pizza.objects.get(id=pizza_id)
    toppings = pizza.entry_set.order_by('name')
    context = {'pizza': pizza, 'toppings': toppings}
    return render(request, 'pizzeria/pizza.html', context)
```

Below are my classes from models.py. The Pizza class is what creates Pizza objects.

```
class Pizza(models.Model):
    """The name of a specific type of pizza."""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the model."""
        return self.name

class Topping(models.Model):
    """toppings that belong to specific types of pizzas"""
    pizza = models.ForeignKey(Pizza, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the model."""
        return self.name
```

I've followed the exercise in this chapter of the book to create a Django project which allows me to create journal entries about specific topics. The code from this journal project works just fine & I've more or less "copy/pasta'd" the code from that exercise into my pizzeria project. The only significant change I've made is that I'd like to sort the toppings by name rather than by the date they were added to the Django database for the project.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42315848/the-function-object-has-no-attribute-entry-set) is very similar to mine but did not resolve my issue.

If there's something I can provide to help with troubleshooting, please let me know.

Comment: Side note: there's a reason the [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) uses pizzas and toppings to explain various details related to ManyToMany relations. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the model is `Topping`, and you did not provide a value for the [**`related_name=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name), you access the `Topping`s with `topping_set`:

```
def pizza(request,pizza_id):
    pizza = Pizza.objects.get(id=pizza_id)
    toppings = pizza.topping_set.order_by('name')
    context = {'pizza': pizza, 'toppings': toppings}
    return render(request, 'pizzeria/pizza.html', context)
```

Comment: Thank you! As I'm new to Django, I assumed that "entry_set" was the proper name of a method/query. I never considered that the name of my class could/would be incorporated into the name of the method/query. Now on to more debugging, thanks!

Comment: @RobertBrown: well the problem with `entry_set` (without an `Entry` class) would be that if you have *multiple* `ForeignKey`s to `Pizza`, it would be ambiguous to what the query refers.